# WCF não conecta ao SQLServer quando publicado no IIS

Tags: c#, sql, iis, wcf

Estou utilizando WCF + SQLServer, quando executo pelo Visual Studio funciona perfeitamente, quando publico e atualizo no IIS ocorre um erro:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)"

já segui diversos fóruns e tutoriais para conexão como:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/

http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html

porém nenhum funcionou, segue o erro completo:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> [FaultException`1: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +153
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type) +336
>   InteligenciaWCF.SistemasAT6WCF.IService1.RecuperarDados(String
>   instrucao) +0
>   InteligenciaWCF.SistemasAT6WCF.Service1Client.RecuperarDados(String
>   instrucao) in c:...    InteligenciaWCF.WCF.receberWCF(String query)
>   in c:...    InteligenciaWCF.GCLogin.lnkAcessar_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:...
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +116
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +106
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +12
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +9754102    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3562

Comment: Como você está conectando ? ADO, EF,... ? Posta o código de sua conexão mas antes certifique-se que os dados de sua connectionstring estejam sendo apontados corretamente.

Comment: SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXXXXX,1433; Database=XXXX; User ID=XXXXX; Password=XXXXX; ");

Comment: Ja tentou tirar a porta ? Por default o SQL SERVER sempre usa a porta 1433 para se conectar. Pelo erro ele não localizou onde está seu servidor SQL. Não chegou nem no login.

Comment: Ja tentei isso também, mas acredito que não seja isso por conta da connectionstring funcionar do Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você colocou a string de conexão correta você pode estar tendo a conexão bloqueada pelo firewall do servidor e terá que abrir a porta no firewallpara acessar o sqlserver.
Siga o tutorial abaixo.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access

Answer (score 0):

Tenho a mesma situação, porém está funcionando. Minha string de conexão é:
Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxx

Verifique se o servico (instância) do sql server está ativa no servidor